# How can I add a column for file/path length to Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

How can I add a column for file/path length in Windows Explorer. For all users in a Windows domain. This is important for me because our projects are copied to CD/DVD and there are built in restrictions in the software we use.  Most of my users have Windows 7 64-bit, but I have 4 Windows XP and 2 Vista users also.

Additionally, is there a way to change the color of the resulting text when it reaches a value of 106 characters length (and again at a value of 212 characters length)?.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

Im sure its possible... somehow.  Here is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to do in XP, but does not work in Windows 7.  Plus this method does require some programming.  I couldnt find a Win7 equivalent.

There are *lots* of Explorer add ons and replacements out there, perhaps one of them has the functionality you want.

Comment: Yeah in Vista they dropped the IColumnProvider that people were using to inject custom columns.  They've replaced it with a property-based system.  So I think the column information must be pulled/populated from the files themselves, and not be made of (arbitrary) info from the file system (like folder sizes or character counts).

Comment: Wouldn't a Window Shell Extension be the proper vehicle?adding columns to Explorer's details view via a column handler shell extension
http://www.codeproject.com/shell/ShellExtGuide8.asp

Comment: @Steven: as mentioned in the comment thread in that article, they won't work in Vista and up because `IColumnProvider` is not supported anymore. As far as I know there's only one third party Explorer-replacement that automatically reads the legacy shell and column handlers, [XPlorer²](http://www.zabkat.com/index.htm).